# What is the proper way of cleaning up asynchronous requests before servlet redeploy (Jersey, Tomcat)?

Tags: java, tomcat, asynchronous, jersey, jax-rs

I have an asynchronous **JAX-RS** API for long-polling clients put together in **Jersey Container Servlet 2.22** and hosted on **Tomcat 7**.

It looks similar to the snippet shown below. It works well in production.

On average 150 long-polling requests are being executed at the same time. It results in almost the **same number of live Tomcat HTTP connections** (according to JMX metrics).  For this low traffic scenario plain-old **HTTP-BIO** connector has been used without problems. No runtime connection leak can be detected provided you use only managed threads :)

```
@Path("/v1/events")
public class LiveEventsResource {

    private static final long longPollTimeoutMs = 30000;

    private ExternalResource externalResource = ExternalResourceProvider.provide();

    private AsyncResponse asyncResponse;

    @POST
    @Path("/liveEvents")
    @ManagedAsync
    public void getResult(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse, RequestPayload payload) {
        this.asyncResponse = asyncResponse;
        asyncResponse.setTimeout(longPollTimeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(new TimeoutHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handleTimeout(AsyncResponse asyncResponseArg) {
                try {
                    asyncResponseArg.cancel();
                } finally {
                    cleanupResources();
                }
            }
        });
        startListeningForExternalEventsAndReturn(payload);
    }

    private void startListeningForExternalEventsAndReturn(RequestPayload payload) {
        externalResource.register(new Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(Event event) {
                respond(event);
            }
        });
    }

    private void respond(Event event) {
        try {
            asyncResponse.resume(event);
        } catch (RuntimeException exception) {
            asyncResponse.resume(exception);
        } finally {
            cleanupResources();
        }
    }

    protected void cleanupResources() {
        externalResource.cleanup();
    }

}
```

The problem I'm facing is that after a successful **Tomcat** redeploy process the number of live connections will apparently increase to about 300 then to 450 and after some further redeploys it will hit the `maxConnection` limit configured for the container.

The clients of the API handle the redeploy by waiting for a client-side timeout (which is of course bigger than the one set at servlet-side) and start polling the API again. But they are guaranteed to send only one request at the same time.

The shape of the monitoring graph on connection count gives a hint. Connection count remains constant after undeployment (connections are not released back to the pool even by `TimeOutHandler`) and starts to increase (allocate new connections) as clients start long-polling again. **In fact, ongoing (suspended) async requests started in the previous context are never relesed until JVM termination!**

After some digging around it's not difficult to find out by analyzing heap dumps made after few redeployments that unreleased, suspended `AsyncResponse` (`AsyncResponder`) instances remain in the memory from previous web application contexts (easily filterable by JQL queries grouped by `Classloader` instances). It's very suspicious too that the same number of out-dated `org.apache.coyote.Request` instances are present in the memory from previous contexts.

I started to look around the undeployment-related source code of the **Jersey Container** hoping that some graceful shutdown process is implemented for async requests with some cleanup actions executed at `@PreDestroy`-time or in `close()` or `dispose()` methods of `Provider`s.

I had an optimistic guess that by running each scheduled `TimeOutHandler`s right before undeployment would solve the problem. But replacing the default `@BackgroundScheduler` provider (`DefaultBackgroundSchedulerProvider`) to a custom implementation and collecting all queued `TimeoutHandler`s of the `Executor` and eventually invoking `AsyncResponse.resume()` or `AsyncResponse.cancel()` on them did not help. This stage might be too late for this cleaning up because request-scope is already shut down.

Any ideas on what my async setup is missing or how **Jersey** can be configured to release the **Servlet Container**'s connections that are still suspended at redeploy-time?

Comment: The connection leak can be reproduced on  **Tomcat 8.0.36** as well.

Comment: in your `respond` method where does `asyncResponse` come from? You don't appear to be storing a reference to that anywhere

Comment: @tddmonkey: Sorry, I didn't included it in the snippet, `asyncResponse` is stored to a (request-scoped) field of the resource.

Comment: Could you update your code? Are you sure the `asyncResponse` is tied to this as you're receiving it through your `getResult` method (I'll admit I'm not 100% sure of the semantics on this)

Comment: @tddmonkey: I've updated the code snippet. `AsyncResponse` is injected by the the JAX-RS container. [link](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10208)

Comment: @tersyxus Did you create a bug report for this? I'm seeing exactly the same symptoms on Payara 4.1.1.171.0.1.

Comment: @HeinBlöd As far as I remember what I had to realize after all was that cleaning up asynchronous requests at webapp-undeploy is the responsibility of the developer not the JAX-RS container. The container is not meant to decide how long it should wait for different ongoing asynchronous requests before interrupting them and how resources initiated by ongoing requests should be destroyed. Cleaning up asynchronous requests is not defined in the JAX-RS specification and there is no proper mechanism for it in Jersey as well. 
I'm going to post further details on what I learned when I have time.

Comment: Related discussion: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/What-is-the-proper-way-of-cleaning-up-asynchronous-requests-before-servlet-redeploy-Jersey-Tomcat-td7583818.html

Comment: Bugreport: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/issues/3920